# Karate mvn clean test does not work as I partially or totally run my features

Tags: maven, automated-tests, karate

I am trying to run my test automation with mvn commands. When I run all features or run features one by one, my match/assert conditions work perfectly fine; however, when I try to use mvn test command, my automation features give unexpected errors from my API's.
I have defined before (callonce function) and after (hooks) scenario and feature conditions in all features' background parts.

mvn clean test
mvn test

mvn clean works fine with no problems. mvn test gives me unexpected errors like the order of API calls inside a scenario or between features are getting all mixed up.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: As instructed in the karate labs, I defined before & after hooks as features. Guessing when clean test works, it runs my automation feature files in parallel threads (?) causing spoils in its order. Can someone please verify?

Answer (score 1):

As I guessed, in the TestRunner class, we give automation a thread count. When I decreased it to 1, the tests started working correctly in order. Not randomly.

It solved my problem. However, I need to learn a more educated way.

Appreciate your comments on this solution!

[image]

Comment: if your tests can't run in parallel, I suggest you fix those problems first

Comment: Yes, that’s a problem caused by using the same default inputs to my API. I am new to the Karate world and still exploring. Been writing java classes to generate random valid numbers to give to my API. Thanks for guidance.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)